# Custom number format for y-axis on Chart

Tags: charts, excel-2010

I have created a chart with 2 axes that acts as a panel chart (see image)

[image: Panel Chart]

As a panel chart I only want to show the portions of the relevant y-axes to the chart next to them. For example, for the right-most y-axis I used a custom number format to exclude anything less than 0:

```
_(* #,##0_);_("";_(* 0??_);_(@_)
```

But for the left most y-axis, I'm stuck. I want to show -400 to positive 400. I've tried 2 different options, but neither is producing the desired effect.

```
[<0](#,##0);[>500000000]"";#,##0_)
[<0](#,##0);[<500000000]#,##0_);""
```

Here is the result I'm looking for:
[image: desired result]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I learned something new today (and a bit weird) regarding formats and chart axes

After some experimenting, this is what I ended up using:

```
[White][>500]_(#,##0_);(#,##0);0;
```

The odd part: When you change the Display Units of the axis (for me, millions), then the formatting no longer recognizes the original amount (500,000,000).

Once I figured that out, I was able to work out the solution.